# Is is bad practice to write a method that does nothing except throw an exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

The title pretty much says it but here is some background:

I have an ASP.Net MVC application where I need to check a list of file paths for existence.  If any of the paths do not exist then an error is returned.

Presently, I have a base controller where the OnException event is implemented.  Here, any unhanded exceptions are dealt with and an error page is returned to the user with the exception's message.

The simplest way for me to do the above check is to write a method that checks each path for existence and if any of them fail, I simply throw (and log) an exception.  This exception is then handled by the base controller and the appropriate message is returned to the user.

My problem is that doing this feels like bad practice.  I am writing a method that returns void and its only purpose is to throw an exception in the rare case that one of the paths does not exist, in most cases it does nothing.  Is this a bad idea?

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? It's a common practice, you can even see examples of it in the .NET framework source code.

Comment: I guess it just felt wrong.  But it's good to get some feedback that this is not the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that.

The .NET framework does this too: for example, `CancellationToken` has a method [`ThrowIfCancellationRequested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested.aspx) which does nothing but throw or not throw depending on some condition.

Another example: `Dispatcher`'s [`VerifyAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.verifyaccess.aspx) method, which checks if the caller is on the same thread as the control is supposed to be accessed on, and throws if not.

Answer (score 0):

On .net exists the option to do a throw new notimplementedexception, so you can create the methods and implement them later. So its not a bad practice, the bad practice is to leave them there when releasing the application to production. Giving errors for no reason is bad practice.

For TDD (test driven development) can be very useful too, you create the method, and then the unit test that fails with the notimplemented exception and finally you implement the method to pass the test.

Btw that was answering the title of your question, butyou should rename the question because your method does something. If it does something and always throws an exception is bad practice, exceptions are costly, you should log the error and move on, without exception. You should better do a PathExists function that returns a Boolean, that's a better solution. (even if someone votes me -1 for no reason... Heheh)

Comment: I've given you a +1 to encourage you to stay on the site, but I also think this isn't a good answer: I think it misses the point of the question. Your example with the `NotImplementedException` is completely different. Also, the third paragraph of your answer is again a bit unrelated, and you should have posted it as a comment.

Comment: The method in question does not always throw an exception, in fact the vast majority of calls will not throw an exception.  An exception is only thrown if one of the paths does not exist, which will not normally be the case.  Returning a boolean also means I loose information about which path is invalid.  BTW, I didn't vote you down, your reasoning is well explained and makes sense but it just doesn't quite fit for my situation.

Comment: Then, is usual business, if it fails it throws an exception, if not, it just returns void. So then is not a bad practice at all, its just a void method that checks something.

Answer (score 0):

Some may say that it's a bad idea but, sometimes, there's no sane alternative.  If you want to raise an exception to communicate an error back to some caller, (perhaps isolated from the raiser by opaque 3rd-party code), then do it. The final arbiter - 'does it work?'